# Can't get background image to show-not path issue

Tags: css, background-image

I'm new at this so I'm sure I'm just missing something. I can't get the background image to show up. I tried all different paths and also tried just copying the image address of a web background to see if that would work.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>REDACTED</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <h1>REDACTED</h1>
        <p>Aspiring Web Developer</p>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href="#"><li class="selected">About Me</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Projects</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<main>
    <img src="img/julie.png">
    <h2>About Me</h2>
    <p>REDACTED</p>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the body CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url('../img/geometry.png');
}
```

Comment: it may be case sentitive, try to check

Comment: with this path: `../img/geometry.png` you must have the folder structure like this: `/index.html || /img || /img/geometry.png || /css` and the body CSS must be in the CSS files into /css folder. It should work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

In your hierarchy, you are trying to go back one directory and then go to img/geometry.png, this is the issue, because when you link the css file in your html, you don't need to use '../', you can access directly img folder!

Try this:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url('img/geometry.png');
}
```

And don't forget to put geometry.png inside the img folder!

Comment: I've tried it both ways:  background-image: url('img/geometry.png'); and background-image: url('../img/geometry.png');. Neither works. I'm pretty sure the latter is the correct path because my file structure is index.html / img / geometry.png

Comment: I also tried just putting geometry.png in the root folder and using background-image: url('geometry.png'); but that also doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

As a @MarcosPerezGude noted, make sure your paths match your directory structure (or possibly visa versa in this case). With what you have provided this is what your directory structure and files should look like:

```
/index.html
/css
    /style.css
    /normalize.css
/img
    /geometry.png
```

And as others have pointed out, the following:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url('../img/geometry.png');
}
```

needs to be in in `style.css` or `normalize.css` with the directory structure given above.